# PortAudio iterate through audio data

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

As I am new to PortAudio, I tried an example program from the internet. The program is able to record the input of a microphone through a callback function.

I want to get **every single sample of the recorded audio** represented as a **numeric value (e.g. float)**. I cannot figure out where the recorded data of the mic is stored.

This is the callback function:

```
static int recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
    unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void *userData)
{
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void)outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void)timeInfo;
    (void)statusFlags;
    (void)userData;
    if (framesLeft < framesPerBuffer)
    {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    if (inputBuffer == NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<framesToCalc; i++)
        {
            *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* left */
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* right */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "SAMPLE" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i<framesToCalc; i++)
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
            //cout << rptr<<endl;
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
        }
    }
    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}
```

The audio input stream is initialized here:

```
err = Pa_OpenStream(
        &stream,
        &inputParameters,
        NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
        SAMPLE_RATE,
        FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
        paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
        recordCallback,
        &data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incoming data is stored in the `inputBuffer` pointer of the callback. Depending on the `inputParameters` used when calling `Pa_OpenStream` one should be able to cast the input buffer into an array of corresponding data type (e.g. if `paFloat32` is used as sample format, then the buffer can be interpreted as `const float*`).

It is recommended that in the callback function you copy the incoming data into another buffer for further processing (outside of the callback).

Multiple channels samples are interleaved in the buffer. For example for stereo input `inputBuffer[0]` is the first sample for the left channer, `inputBuffr[1]` is the first sample to the right channel, `inputBuffer[2]` is the 2nd sample for the left channel, etc. Total number of samples is provided via `framesPerBuffer` argument of the callback.

Comment: Can you tell me which of the parameters at the initialization (2nd code snipped) is the inputBuffer? I understood now where it is located in the callback.

Comment: @bingoStack There is no input buffer at initialization. It will be handed to you via the callback function. You can adjust though the inputParameters structure to tell how many channels you want and what is the sample format, see http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/structPaStreamParameters.html

Comment: Thanks! Although, I am not able to read the data. I just added `cout << *(float*)(inputBuffer) << endl`; before `return finished` in the callback and I get either 0 or +/- 3.0517e-005. What is wrong?

Comment: @bingoStack You can do indeed `*(const float*)(inputBuffer)` to get the very first sample. Also check that you are recording from a correct device (see device index in inputParameters).

Comment: Thanks; mic was deactivated.

Comment: Is it right, that the recordCallback function records always one sample (=one float) when it is called?

Comment: @bingoStack The audio data exchange (recording/playback) is performed in frames (buffers containing several samples). Number of samples per frame is provided via `framesPerBuffer` argument of the callback.